# Window Form Closing Event

Tags: winforms

I am using C# for creating a window form application. In which I am using the MDI interface.

But I want to make like that:

```
private void Earnings_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to Quite this form","confirmation Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

    if(result==DialogResult.Yes)
    {
       this.Close();
    }
    else if (result == DialogResult.No)
    {
       Earnings sibling = new Earnings();
       sibling.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
       sibling.Show();
    }
}
```

But this is not working the form will close in both conditions please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct, however WinForms have the tendency to close itself when hits an error. 
You must ensure that the reason of closing is the DialogResult.

Please change the part of your code with the following:

```
private void Earnings_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to Quite this form","confirmation Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

    if(result==DialogResult.Yes)
    {
 MessageBox.Show("You selected Yes", "Yes Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
       this.Close();
    }
    else if (result == DialogResult.No)
    {
 MessageBox.Show("You selected No", "No Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
       Earnings sibling = new Earnings();
       sibling.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
       sibling.Show();
    }
}
```

If you see the dialogboxes, you will know the code works properly or not.